# ON DELETE внешних ключей трёх и более таблиц в SQLite3

Tags: sqlite3, foreign-key

У меня есть три таблицы: schedules, pairs, pairs_places. Структура таблиц:

schedules

- id (Первичный ключ)
- gid
- day
- photo_id
- can_clean

pairs

- id (Первичный ключ)
- schedule_id (Внешний ключ на schedules.id. ON DELETE CASCADE)
- ptime
- sort
- name

pairs_places

- id (Первичный ключ)
- pair_id (Внешний ключ на pairs.id. ON DELETE CASCADE)
- teacher_id
- pair_place

При удалении записи из schedules (`DELETE FROM schedules WHERE id=1`) я хочу чтобы все записи из pairs и pairs_places, связанные с удалённой записью тоже удалились. То есть удалятся все записи из pairs, которые связаны с schedule, а так же записи из pairs_places, которые связаны с удалёнными записями из pairs. Но когда я провожу этот запрос, удаляется запись из schedules, удаляются записи из pairs, но не из pairs_places. Поддерживает ли SQLite3 подобное удаление? Если да, то как мне настроить БД чтобы проблема решилась?

Answer (score 0):

Я смог добиться желаемого результата с помощью триггеров.

```
CREATE TRIGGER pairs_cleaner AFTER DELETE ON pairs
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM pairs_places WHERE pairs_places.pair_id = OLD.id;
END
```

Записи из pairs удаляются засчёт связи внешним ключом, а записи из pairs_places удаляются, когда удаляются и pairs.